# Problem with Android Views

Tags: java, android, view, grid

I have the following code:
http://pastebin.com/hgHePi4K

(Couldn't manage to  it)

My problem is that, whenever I drag a tile and then release it, it doesn't snap to the grid graphically. My debug statements (BFW.showMessage) all show up, and show correct information however, I can't see the Tile snapped to grid, only where I released it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: For a start i suggest you use `mWidth` instead of `_w`. It makes your code more understandable.

Comment: Fixed it, the absoulte x coordinate wasn't properly updated, therefore the tile remained on its last move position.
Thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: @Levex: Post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: I'M a new user and therefore I couldn't answer my own question within 24 hours. Posted the answer now, I can accept it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, the absoulte x coordinate wasn't properly updated, therefore the tile remained on its last move position.
Thanks for the help anyways.